# What is the best way to wire an audio interface with 1/4 outputs to studio monitors that have an XLR input?

Tags: xlr, input

I have a scarlet audio interface with 1/4 outputs, and I'm thinking about purchasing EVENT 20/30s. The 20/30s have XLR inputs. What is the best way to connect the two without losing sound quality?

Answer (score 3):

You just use two *balanced* audio cables with XLR on the speaker side and 1/4-inch on the audio interface side. That is a very standard pro audio cable.

Comment: To clarify, you want a cable that has a TRS (tip, ring, sleeve) plug on the 1/4 inch end.. not a TS (tip, sleeve).  And a Male XLR on the other end.